# Why can't I change values in my cookies?

Tags: 6, cookies

I'm storing my users city in a cookie.

I want that cookie to expire by browser session, so I don't want to store this information in $_SESSION, because I want $_SESSION to persist for the default 23ish days.

So I'd like to stick with Drupal storing all of its stuff in $_SESSION as normal, but also set a cookie with a custom lifetime. When the user selects a city I set a cookie in my forms `_form_submit()` hook:

```
$c = 'Washington'; // ...or whatever
$_COOKIE['city']['cityname'] = $c;
setcookie('city[cityname]', $_COOKIE['city']['cityname'], 0);
```

If I print this out with `print_r($_COOKIE['city'])` I get:

```
Array ( [cityname] => Washington [state] => 65 )
```

Yay, it works!

Then the user selects a new city and the same code runs again (I know it's running because I've tried inserting a `die;` in there):

```
$c = 'New York';
$_COOKIE['city']['cityname'] = $c;
setcookie('city[cityname]', $_COOKIE['city']['cityname'], 0);
```

I print the $COOKIE value out again and get:

```
Array ( [cityname] => Washington [state] => 65 )
```

So the value hasn't changed and I'm left with the previous city. Why aren't my cookies values changing? Is there a way I can fix this, or a recommended workaround available?

Comment: $c = 'New York'; setcookie('city[cityname]', $c, 0); Try this, the value is stored through setcookie(), not by setting the variable.

Comment: Shouldn't the value in the hash be equal to $c after l set it? Or is there something magical going on there? I'm setting the value in the hash as well in case some other code accesses the hash later on, but maybe setcookie() does that for me? Thanks for the answer, I'll try ditching explicitly setting the hash when I'm back at work tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the issue I think. The first cookie is set from the homepage. The second was set from a different page.

I looked in the Chrome "cookies" dialog and found out that I had multiple cookies all set with different paths.

`setcookie()` has a "`$path`" argument:

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will 
>   be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available
>   within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default
>   value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

So in my `setcookie()` I now do:

```
setcookie('region[state]', $state, 0, '/');
```

...and the path gets saved to "/" every time, and I don't end up with duplicate cookies causing confusion.